# Execute migration files using ActiveRecord without rails doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I'm trying to execute migration files using gem 'active_record' in a local host app that doesn't use rails and use a sqlite database.

I have the following rake file:

```
require_relative './config/environments.rb'
require 'active_record'

task :default => :migrate

desc "executing migration"
task :migrate do   
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('/db/migrate', ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil)
end
```

inside the /db/migrate path i have a file called 001_create_users.rb with the following code:

```
require 'active_record'

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def self.up
        create_table: users do |u|
            u.string :username
            u.string :password_digest
        end
     end
end
```

but whe I execute rake on terminal the table users is not created on the database, just a table called **schema_migrations** is created.

On the ActiveRecord i get the following records:

```
D, [2014-07-10T11:42:21.520400 #2042] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (7.2ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(255) NOT NULL) [0m
D, [2014-07-10T11:42:21.520842 #2042] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  select sqlite_version(*)
D, [2014-07-10T11:42:21.522101 #2042] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")[0m
```

What I need to do in order to create property my **Users** table?

Comment: Related: [*Generate migrations outside Rails*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882345/generate-migrations-outside-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `standalone_migrations` gem? (https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations)