# How to use ActiveRecord outside Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I'm building a Rails application based on hexagonal architecture.

One of my adapters is storage adapter (maintained as a gem) that manages access to database and provides simple interface for rails application to store and query data in database.

I'd like to use `ActiveRecord` in this gem with all `rake` tasks (create, migrate, drop, rollback) for managing database.

How can I use AR outside rails, but with all rake tasks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ActiveRecord in a ruby script outside Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643875/how-to-use-activerecord-in-a-ruby-script-outside-rails)

Comment: If you want something that works. Here is an example. Run bundle install & migrate your DB. Your done. README for more info. https://github.com/slindsey3000/ContactManager

Comment: Related: [*Generate migrations outside Rails*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882345/generate-migrations-outside-rails)

Answer (score 18):

Install it like any other gem

```
gem install activerecord
```

Then you configure it somewhere like this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => 'mysql',
  :database => 'database',
  :username => 'user',
  :password => 'password',
  :host     => 'localhost')
```

Models can then inherit as normal from ActiveRecord::Base

You get all of the rake tasks but you do have to do some extra configuration since you will not have the Rails.  Here is the link inside of activerecord for how to configure that stuff.

[Database tasks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I have so far. My problem is to have all `rake` tasks for managing database in my gem as well.

Comment: Here is a relevant github issue discussing your use case, with example code. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11609

Answer (score 2):

An updated solution is the [standalone_migrations](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations). Basically after doing the configuration for the gem and creating the configuration, you have access to all the ActiveRecord niceties. Rake tasks included!

Also, I made a small generator for scaffolding simple scripts that have access to ActiveRecord out of the box: [nrb - Ninja Ruby](https://github.com/shuriu/nrb).